# Rendering Material Variables

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, opengl, 3d

I am writing a material script interpreter in C++ which is nothing special in fact. A simple material may look something like this:

```
Material "SimpleMaterial"
{
    CastShadows true
    Transparent false

    Technique
    {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

As any other material it has multiple techniques, passes, texture units, each of them have own settings. But materials will also support variables which I'm having a bit difficulty to do. A variable in a material script looks like this:

```
Material "SimpleMaterial2"
{
    Boolean SomeVariable true

    CastShadows SomeVariable
    Transparent SomeVariable
    ...
}
```

Now what I am trying to understand is what is a best way to make a Variable class for material. A variable must hold a list of all properties that it is assigned to. So if I now change SomeVariable to false, it must set both CastShadows and Transparent values of SimpleMaterial2 to false. And also a material itself must hold list of variables that affect its properties. For example if I have this materials:

```
Material "SimpleParent"
{
    Boolean SomeVariable true
    ...
}

Material "SimpleDerived" : "SimpleParent"
{
    CastShadows SomeVariable
    ... 
}
```

If I now change CastShadows in Derived material it must notify the SomeVariable to remove this property from assignments or something. Currently I have a variable class that looks something like this:

```
class Variable
{ 
public:
    enum Assignment 
    { 
        CastShadows,
        Transparent,
        Pass_Diffuse,
        ...
    }
    .
    enum ValueType
    {
        Boolean,
        Enum,
        Vec3,
        ...
    }
.
private:
    map<void*, std::vector<Assignment>> _Assignments;
    ValueType _Type;
    void*     _Value;
}
```

The _Value void pointer actually stores values of different types depending of what type this variable is (bool, int, Vector2...). _Assignments map is actually a sort of list that stores all information where this variable is assigned to. Void pointer can be either pointer to material, materials technique, technique's pass, texture unit, and the vector that is stored under the key stores all assignment where this value "points to". So when variable's value is changed it calls an update method. This update method first iterates through map and gets each vector from map. Then it iterates through vector and checks which assignment. So if assignments is CastShadow, then it converts:

```
((SL_Material*)(*map_iterator).first)->CastShadows = (bool*)_Value;
```

This method works fine as long as I make sure that (void*) pointers are properly returned to their originals. But I am pretty sure that all this can be done in more clean way. Perhaps using some templates? Any ideas are welcomed :)

Comment: Looks like you're reinventing a "variant" type.  Just imho (opinion) but these schemes almost always generate code smell because they become too complex.  Prefer a model where you specify what a material is, ignoring the parameters you don't use for any specific material.  That is much cleaner.

Comment: The thing is that using "variables" enables me to create material inheritance. A base material may have 10 techniques with different passes which can easily turn into long scripts. Imagine rewriting all the code...but by defining variables I can put for example 2 string, one for diffuse map and other for normal map and use them in every pass. Now I can create a derived material with just a few lines of code (only changing values of these two variables). Variables are not kept after end of script parsing.

Comment: Not directly related, but note that names starting with `_[A-Z]` are reserved for any use for the implementation.